# WebRTC setRemoteDescription error

Tags: javascript, webrtc, sdp

I wanted to test connection between my c++ app and browser javascript. For now i have no server involved and i'm doing signaling stuff on my own by standard IO. The issue is when I try to pass sdp generated by native app to javascript to create answer I get error (generated at setRemoteDescription call):

```
OperationError: Failed to parse SessionDescription. a=sctpmap:5000 webrtc-datachannel 1024 Invalid SDP line.
```

Here is javascript code:

```
function input() {
  var stdin = document.getElementById('stdin');
  var input = stdin.value;
  stdin.value = '';
  return input;
}
function answer() {
  peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(pcConfig);
  peerConnection.onicecandidate = onIceCandidate;
  peerConnection.ondatachannel  = onDataChannel;
  peerConnection.oniceconnectionstatechange = onIceConnectionStateChange;
  var buff = input();
  var sdpOffer = {
    type: "offer",
    sdp: buff
  }
  peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(sdpOffer).then(() => onSetRemoteSuccess(peerConnection), onSetSessionDescriptionError);
  peerConnection.createAnswer().then(onCreateAnswerSuccess, onCreateSessionDescriptionError);
}
```

and sample sdp:

```
v=0
o=- 8612289788290620730 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE data
a=msid-semantic: WMS
m=application 49168 DTLS/SCTP 5000
c=IN IP4 77.114.92.160
a=candidate:1774547698 1 udp 2113937151 77.114.92.160 49168 typ host generation 0 network-cost 50
a=ice-ufrag:yzpQ
a=ice-pwd:UDjI4/ifwEV4mbZnfjbJrRW1
a=ice-options:trickle
a=fingerprint:sha-256 3C:60:34:BA:24:44:36:72:10:DF:E4:8C:00:0B:C1:3D:87:12:65:4D:AC:FF:09:F2:DD:22:BD:A8:3C:90:F1:F8
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:data
a=sctpmap:5000 webrtc-datachannel 1024
```

Connection between two native apps works fine so i guess the issue is somewhere in javascript code. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: It works fine in firefox the issue is occuring in google chrome. Any suggestions what it can be?

Comment: Did you find the solution? I am also facing the same.

Comment: I ended up making a simple server using socket.io and it worked well. I don't remember exacly what the issue was, but involving server as a signaling service helped.

Answer (score 1):

Add an line break after the last line `a=sctpmap:5000 webrtc-datachannel 1024`

Comment: Verified that a missing line break could cause issues in chrome!